# Is there a way to edit a response body?

Tags: python, https, python-requests, fiddler, charles-proxy

I have just started using the `requests` module in Python, I can `get` and `post` without any issues. However, I am wondering whether there is a way to be able to modify the 'response body' and then send this back using Python.

This would be like editing a request on the likes of Fiddler, Charles or Proxyman.

Any advice would be much appreciated, as I am not even sure if this is possible.

Comment: It is easy and documented how to retrieve the body. What have you tried to modify it so far?

Comment: Problem is not retrieving the body, I want to be able to modify the body and then send it back, or 'intercept' it then send it.

Comment: Here on Stack Overflow it is expected that you present the code you already have and tell us where you are stuck.

Comment: As you seem to be familiar with Python you should also consider `mitmproxy` which can be extended by Python scripts. There are a lot example scripts available https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/addons-examples/

Comment: You can use the Scripting tool from `Proxyman` app to write a Javascript script to modify your response (includes Headers, Body, Status Code, ...). There are a lot of snippet code that you can reuse https://docs.proxyman.io/scripting/snippet-code